# Question on Independent Events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have this example from the All of Statistics book:

[image]

I'm looking for an explanation for P(A2). Why is it equal to (2/3)(3/4)(1/3)?

Thanks

Comment: This is explained on the previous line. The reason $P(A_2)=(2/3)(3/4)(1/3)$ is "$A_2$ occurs if we have the sequence person 1 misses, person 2 misses, person 1 succeeds."

Comment: Because of indep[endence,  the probability of "person 1 misses, and person 2 misses, and person 1 succeeds" is the product of the three probabilities. The probability person 1 misses his first shot is 2/3, the probability person 2 misses his first shot is 3/4, the probability person 1 makes his second shot is 1/3.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

Symbolically,

\begin{align}
P(A_2) & = P(\text{$P_1$ succeeds before $P_2$, on trial $2$}) \\
       & = P(\text{$P_1$ fails on trial $1$ and succeeds on trial $2$})
    \times P(\text{$P_2$ fails on trial $1$}) \\
       & = P(\text{$P_1$ fails on trial $1$})
    \times P(\text{$P_1$ succeeds on trial $2$})
    \times P(\text{$P_2$ fails on trial $1$}) \\
       & = \frac23 \times \frac13 \times \frac34 = \frac16
\end{align}

Keep in mind that the players take turns, so Player $1$ takes their second turn before Player $2$ does.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.